# Prove that $\arg \frac{(z_3-z_2)}{(z_3-z_1)} = \frac12 \arg\frac{ z_2}{z_1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|$

I have used:
$z_1=x_1+\mathrm iy_1,z_2=x_2+\mathrm iy_2,z_3=x_3+\mathrm iy_3$
and obtained $$\arg\frac{z_3-z_2}{z_3-z_1} = \arctan \frac{(y_3-y_2)(x_3-x_1)-(y_3-y_1)(x_3-x_2)}{(x_3-x_2)(x_3-x_1)}$$
But, then I'm stuck.

Urgent help needed.

Comment: Why don't you use polar coordinates instead for $z_1,z_2,z_3$?

Comment: @Shahab, how would that work? using r1,theta1...etc?

Comment: Let $z_i=re^{i\theta_i}$ for $i=1,2,3$. Then 
$\frac{z_3-z_2}{z_3-z_1}=\frac{e^{i\theta_3}-e^{i\theta_2}}{e^{i\theta_3}-e^{i\theta_1}}=\frac{\cos\theta_3-\cos\theta_2+i(\sin\theta_3-\sin\theta_2)}{\cos\theta_3-\cos\theta_1+i(\sin\theta_3-\sin\theta_1)}$

Comment: I think the complex-analysis tag is misleading

Comment: @RowanS it is a problem from the book introductory complex analysis by silverman. So, I believe the tag is appropiate.

Comment: @Shahab ok, so, I know Theta is the argument so how would I get the argument for that term? and did the rs disappear because the magnitudes of all the zs are equal to each other?

Comment: Sorry, I agree with RowanS now that the question is incorrect.

Comment: This is problem #16 in Chapter 1 of the Silverman Introductory Complex analysis book. how can the question be incorrect?

Comment: Yes but it's not an analysis problem it's a complex numbers question. Just because complex analysis involves complex numbers doesn't mean all questions involving complex numbers should be tagged complex analysis.

Comment: The question is actually a very easy geometric question and is equivalent to the well known circle theorem that the angle subtended at the centre of a circle is double the size of the angle subtended at the edge from the same two points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$arg({a \over b})=arg(a)-arg(b)$

So your problem becomes...

$arg(z_3-z_2)-arg(z_3-z_1)=\frac{1}{2}(arg(z_2)-arg(z_1))$

Now let $z_k=re^{i\theta_k}=r(\cos{\theta_k+i\sin{\theta_k}})$

$arg(r(\cos{\theta_3}-\cos{\theta_2}+i(\sin{\theta_3}-\sin{\theta_2})))-arg(r(\cos{\theta_3}-\cos{\theta_1}+i(\sin{\theta_3}-\sin{\theta_1})))=\frac{1}{2}(arg(r(\cos{\theta_2+i\sin{\theta_2}}))-arg(r(\cos{\theta_1+i\sin{\theta_1}})))$

$arctan({\sin{\theta_3}-\sin{\theta_2} \over \cos{\theta_3}-\cos{\theta_2}})-arctan({\sin{\theta_3}-\sin{\theta_1} \over \cos{\theta_3}-\cos{\theta_1}})={1 \over 2}(arctan({\sin{\theta_2} \over \cos{\theta_2}})-arctan({{\sin{\theta_1} \over \cos{\theta_1}}}))$

It can be proven with trig identities that ${{\sin{x}-\sin{y}} \over {\cos{x}-\cos{y}} }={\cot({\frac{x+y}{-2}})}$

$arctan({\cot({\frac{\theta_3+\theta_2}{-2}})})-arctan({\cot({\frac{\theta_3+\theta_1}{-2}})})={1 \over 2}(arctan(\tan{\theta_2})-arctan(\tan{\theta_1})$

It can be shown that $arctan(\cot{x})={\pi \over 2}-x$

$({\pi \over 2} - \frac{\theta_3+\theta_2}{-2})-({\pi \over 2} - \frac{\theta_3+\theta_1}{-2})={1 \over 2}({\theta_2}-{\theta_1})$

$\frac{\theta_3+\theta_2}{2}-\frac{\theta_3+\theta_1}{2}={1 \over 2}({\theta_2}-{\theta_1})$

$\frac{\theta_3+\theta_2-\theta_3-\theta_1}{2}={1 \over 2}({\theta_2}-{\theta_1})$

$\frac{\theta_2-\theta_1}{2}={1 \over 2}({\theta_2}-{\theta_1})$

The statement appears to be proven, but be aware that this makes many assumptions, largest of which is that the angles all exist in the first quadrant. If the angles were all in different quadrants, the proof would be much more involved, and to make such a proof would need a lot of meticulous calculations and studying many different cases - mostly because of the arctan function and its limited range.

Good luck.

Comment: thank you! I was trying it with polar coordinates just now and got stuck with the cotx, I was doing it backwards. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the statement is true. The equation doesn't work for $z_1=z_2=z_3=1$

Comment: it never said the three zs were equal to 1 just equal to each other.

Comment: I think his point is that if they do not work for z1=z2=z3=1, the statement cannot be true because it does not work for all possibilities of z1, z2, and z3.